# Positive lookabehind working 'too well' in regex

Tags: regex, lookbehind

The pattern is matching more than intended. If any one could explain why 'address' is matched when it's part of the lookbehind and how to prevent that. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Pattern:

```
(?<=@address|)[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^\]\[]*\])
```

String:

```
test [@address|singleline second] test
```

Results:

```
address singleline second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `|`:

```
(?<=@address\|)[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^\]\[]*\])
```

since `(?<=@address|)` asserts that the matched-string is preceded either by `@address` or by the empty string. (And since *everything* is *always* preceded by the empty string, that has no effect.)

By the way, a small terminological note: `(?<=@address|)` is called look*behind*, not look*ahead*. A look*ahead* assertion, such as your `(?=[^\]\[]*\])`, asserts that a given point in the regex is (or is not) *followed* by a specified pattern.

Comment: Thx. Makes perfect sense. Appreciate the extra explanation I got lookahead just rolling over that part of the pattern in RegExr. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

the look-arounds aren't even necessary.

You appear to want the result to be 'singleline'. (your token a-zA-Z is only letters, and the interior data is space delimited, the entire pattern would be that.)

And address| is static.

so, why not do less looking around, and just *consume*:

```
/@address\|(\w+).*?\]/g   //$1 has the capture.
```

one possible benefit, besides being simpler: If you had to run this globally on lots of data, you'd have matched up to that last `]`, instead of only up to the `e` in 'singleline'.